# How to get value in href tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want "Birmingham, AL" which i would press in html page can be selected and autofill the form in next html page.

```
    <tr><td><h2><a href="KF.html">Birmingham, AL</a></h2></td><td>212,247</td></tr>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, you should provide more details, show what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Whenever i press Birmingham it moves to next page name "KF.html". There is form in KF.html. I want Birmingham to be filled in that form. Further assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass "Birmingham, AL" as a URL parameter to KF.html and get that on the next page to put it in your form.